# Select SQL with specifc decimals number

Tags: sql, select, decimal, mysql-workbench, wildcard

I need search rows that have a specifc decimals numbers

```
|product | value |
|--------|-------|
|prodA   | 1.3599|
|prodB   | 1.6222|
|prodC   | 1.2566|
|prodD   | 1.1000|
```

If I use the script `select * from product where value like '%_.___%';` the result is all values in table with 3 or more decimals case.

But I need bring only the row that have decimals number > 5 in the third decimal place in the table example I need the **products A and C** that have number > 5 in the third decimal place, there some script or wildcards that bring this result?

Answer (score 0):

One method is to convert the value to a string and then use string operations:

```
where substr(format(value, 4), -2, 1) >= '5'
```

Note:  This can get a bit tricky with rounding, because 4.9999999 might be interpreted as 5.0000.

You can also use arithmetic:

```
where mod(cast( value * 1000 as int), 10) >= 5
```